# How to not make a chrome extension onclick

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Ok So I converted a bookmarklet to a chrome extension and, basically what happened was that I had to click the chrome extension icon to activate the bookmarklet. So my bookmarklet shows an alert whenever a website with the word 'unblocked" and that won't work, because I don't want it to be on click.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClick.addListener(function(tab) {
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "bookmarklet.js"})
```

});

ok so how would i make the chrome extension just run in the background without clicking the icon

Answer (score 0):

Your question is ambiguous. From what I understood, you might want a [content script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_scripts) which can read/modify the content shown by a page. You can use the `matches` property to specify URLs on which the content script will run.

Comment: well, yes, but I want to know how I can make the chrome extension run in the background, without clicking it every time to activate it.

Comment: You did not clarify anything in this comment, again your question is still ambiguous. Content scripts run when a page is loaded, regardless of if you click the extension icon or not. There are also [Background scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/background) which execute logic in the background, but if you want to change the content of a page then Content scripts are the only valid way.